# IE9 jquery slidedown effect issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, effect, slideup

So i have a ul list where i click a div above it and then i toggle it so i can slidedown/up the list... but when i slidedown the list on IE9 i see this weird effect below it:

[image]

this happens on slideUp

my code looks like this:

```
    $(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
        $(".slide_menu").slideUp("fast");
    }else{
        $(".slide_menu").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

html looks like this:

```
        <div class="btn">Button</a></div>
    <ul class="slide_menu">
    <li><a href="http://domain.com">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the html as well? :)

Comment: no problem , see the main post.

Comment: @fxuser: Can you post your CSS as well? Are you using box shadow?

Comment: Yeah, box shadow could potentially screw it up, I mean it's IE we're talking about ^^

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? v1.5.1 was the [first version to support IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/02/jquery-1-5-1-supports-ie9.aspx). Also which [Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mode is IE9 rendering your site as? The wrong mode can lead to unwanted problems.

Comment: i am only using text-shadow:0 2px 4px #828260; on btn class - i am using v1.6 jquery version - IE9 is rendering as IE9 standards in document mode... as default i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is toggle it on clicks, try this. Altered your code just a bit, I don't have IE9 because I'm on a mac but this should work. If it still doesn't work. Tell me and I'll see what I can do!

http://jsfiddle.net/fWJuk/1/

Comment: Then your problem is probably the css, with box shadow I think. If the javascript behaves as it should, then try without box shadow and see if you still have the same problem. IE probably has some problems rendering this nicely with the animation and box shadow.

Comment: i dont use box shadow but instead text shadow, i removed it from the css, every css from the (btn, slide_menu) but it still shows these weird lines...

Comment: it was a parent div which was causing it and it had box shadow on it.. now i have to find a fix for it cause it ruins a bit the design.. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `height` css style set at `100%` for the `html` or the `body` element, removing it could solve the IE9 box-shadow rendering issue. This worked for me. I know, IE9 should have done this properly in the first place. This looks like a IE9 bug.